# In IIS 7, Is APP Pool/DefaultAppPool user part of EVERYONE user group?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

If I give full control to EVERYONE user on domain level, does it mean that local virtual user, APP Pool/DefaultAppPool user gets access to the folder too?

Answer (score 0):

Local users will not have the same permissions as domain users. If you require this functionality, I believe the AppPool will need to run under a DOMAIN\USER account